# How can I get a TreeView branch by name rather than value?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, branch

Is there any way to get a `TreeView` branch by name?
For example, if I have a `TreeView` menu like so:

```
TreeItem<String> root, branch;

root = new TreeItem<>();
root.setExpanded(true);

branch = makeBranch("Chicken", root);

makeBranch("Hen", branch);
```

Here is the `makeBranch()` method:

```
public TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String s, TreeItem<String> parent){

    TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(s);
    item.setExpanded(true);

    parent.getChildren().add(item);
    return item;
}
```

Now if I want to get a branch, I can do:

```
branch.getChildren().get(a_number); // get using index
```

But is there anyway I can get a branch by its name rather than value?
So something like:

```
branch.getChildren().get("the name of leaf or branch");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`TreeItem.getChildren()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#getChildren--) returns a [`ObservableList<TreeItem<T>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html), you can use the methods of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to find the child you're looking for, e.g. using [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to filter the content:

```
final String value = "the name of leaf or branch";
Optional<TreeItem<String>> nodeOptional = branch.getChildren().stream()
                                                .filter(
                                                    (child)-> child.getValue().equals(value)
                                                 )
                                                .findFirst();

if (nodeOptional.isPresent()) {
    TreeItem<String> item = nodeOptional.get();
    // do something with item
} else {
    // no child with specified value was found
}
```

Note that you only search the **direct** children of `branch` that way. If you want to find arbitrary descendants of `branch`, you have to do a [tree search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).